# "The system cannot find the batch label specified" error message

Tags: batch-file

Here is my code in batch. Save as Avalanche.bat. I keep getting the error `The system cannot find the batch label specified`. If anybody can fix this, please let me know!

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo off
title Avalanche
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Avalanche.bat) do set color=%%x
color %color%
if exist control.txt goto controlsetup
goto menu

:menu
    :: Main menu ::
    mode con cols=76 lines=12
        echo.
        echo   .:mmmm:.                                                        .:mmmm:.
        echo  ,mmMMMMmm,    .   .   .   .   .      .   .   .  .... .  . ....  ,mmMMMMmm,
        echo  :mMMMMMMm:  .: :. :. .: .: :. :    .: :. ::  : :     :  : :     :mMMMMMMm:
        echo  'mmMMMMmm'  :...:  :.:  :...: :    :...: : : : :     :::: :'''  'mmMMMMmm'
        echo   ':mmmm:'   :   :   :   :   : :::: :   : :  :: '.... :  : :...   ':mmmm:'
        echo.
        echo                                   1) PLAY
        echo                                   2) HELP
        echo                                   3) EXIT
        echo.
    choice /c 123 /n >nul
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto setup
    if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto help
    if %errorlevel% equ 3 exit
    goto menu

:help
    :: Help menu ::
    mode con cols=31 lines=12
    cls
        echo.
        echo            Help
        echo.
        echo  To play Avalanche, simply use
        echo  the A and D keys to move left
        echo  and right, respectively. If
        echo  you are hit by a falling
        echo  boulder, you die and lose the
        echo  game. During the game, press
        echo  Q to quit and P to pause.
        echo.
        echo      1) Change Color
        echo      2) Return to Menu
        echo.
    choice /c 12 /n >nul
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto color
    if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto menu
    goto help
:color
    :: Color changer ::
    mode con cols=35 lines=17
    cls
            echo.
            echo  Type two characters for their
            echo  corresponding colors. The first
            echo  color is the background and the
            echo  second is the text color. The
            echo  two cannot be the same color.
            echo.
            echo  0 = Black       8 = Gray
            echo  1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
            echo  2 = Green       A = Light Green
            echo  3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
            echo  4 = Red         C = Light Red
            echo  5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
            echo  6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
            echo  7 = White       F = Bright White
            echo.
        set /p "color=Color: "
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto color
    color !color!
    echo !color!>>Avalanche.bat
    goto help

:controlsetup
        title Game Controls
        mode con cols=30 lines=1
:controlchoice
        choice /c adqp /n
        if !errorlevel! equ 1 set "dir=left"
        if !errorlevel! equ 2 set "dir=right"
        if !errorlevel! equ 3 set "dir=quit"
        if !errorlevel! equ 4 set "dir=pause"
goto controlwrite
:controlwrite
        echo !dir!>>control.txt
        if !dir! equ quit exit
        goto controlchoice

:setup
    set "b=O"

:play
    echo stop>>control.txt
    start Avalanche.bat
    mode con cols=16 lines=14

    set "b0y=1000"
    set "b1y=1000"
    set "b2y=1000"
    set "b3y=1000"
    set "b4y=1000"
    set "b5y=1000"
    set "b6y=1000"
    set "b7y=1000"
    set "b8y=1000"
    set "b9y=1000"
    set "px=5"


:loop
(


                    :: Resetting the board ::
                    set "0,0= "
                    set "0,1= "
                    set "0,2= "
                    set "0,3= "
                    set "0,4= "
                    set "0,5= "
                    set "0,6= "
                    set "0,7= "
                    set "0,8= "
                    set "0,9= "
                    set "1,0= "
                    set "1,1= "
                    set "1,2= "
                    set "1,3= "
                    set "1,4= "
                    set "1,5= "
                    set "1,6= "
                    set "1,7= "
                    set "1,8= "
                    set "1,9= "
                    set "2,0= "
                    set "2,1= "
                    set "2,2= "
                    set "2,3= "
                    set "2,4= "
                    set "2,5= "
                    set "2,6= "
                    set "2,7= "
                    set "2,8= "
                    set "2,9= "
                    set "3,0= "
                    set "3,1= "
                    set "3,2= "
                    set "3,3= "
                    set "3,4= "
                    set "3,5= "
                    set "3,6= "
                    set "3,7= "
                    set "3,8= "
                    set "3,9= "
                    set "4,0= "
                    set "4,1= "
                    set "4,2= "
                    set "4,3= "
                    set "4,4= "
                    set "4,5= "
                    set "4,6= "
                    set "4,7= "
                    set "4,8= "
                    set "4,9= "
                    set "5,0= "
                    set "5,1= "
                    set "5,2= "
                    set "5,3= "
                    set "5,4= "
                    set "5,5= "
                    set "5,6= "
                    set "5,7= "
                    set "5,8= "
                    set "5,9= "
                    set "6,0= "
                    set "6,1= "
                    set "6,2= "
                    set "6,3= "
                    set "6,4= "
                    set "6,5= "
                    set "6,6= "
                    set "6,7= "
                    set "6,8= "
                    set "6,9= "
                    set "7,0= "
                    set "7,1= "
                    set "7,2= "
                    set "7,3= "
                    set "7,4= "
                    set "7,5= "
                    set "7,6= "
                    set "7,7= "
                    set "7,8= "
                    set "7,9= "
                    set "8,0= "
                    set "8,1= "
                    set "8,2= "
                    set "8,3= "
                    set "8,4= "
                    set "8,5= "
                    set "8,6= "
                    set "8,7= "
                    set "8,8= "
                    set "8,9= "
                    set "9,0= "
                    set "9,1= "
                    set "9,2= "
                    set "9,3= "
                    set "9,4= "
                    set "9,5= "
                    set "9,6= "
                    set "9,7= "
                    set "9,8= "
                    set "9,9= "


                :: Set player and boulders ::
                set "!px!,0=@"

                if !b0y! lss 0 set "b0y=1000"
                if !b1y! lss 0 set "b1y=1000"
                if !b2y! lss 0 set "b2y=1000"
                if !b3y! lss 0 set "b3y=1000"
                if !b4y! lss 0 set "b4y=1000"
                if !b5y! lss 0 set "b5y=1000"
                if !b6y! lss 0 set "b6y=1000"
                if !b7y! lss 0 set "b7y=1000"
                if !b8y! lss 0 set "b8y=1000"
                if !b9y! lss 0 set "b9y=1000"

                if !b0y! leq 9 if !b0y! geq 0 set /a "b0y=!b0y!-1"
                set "0,!b0y!=!b!"
                if !b1y! leq 9 if !b1y! geq 0 set /a "b1y=!b1y!-1"
                set "1,!b1y!=!b!"
                if !b2y! leq 9 if !b2y! geq 0 set /a "b2y=!b2y!-1"
                set "2,!b2y!=!b!"
                if !b3y! leq 9 if !b3y! geq 0 set /a "b3y=!b3y!-1"
                set "3,!b3y!=!b!"
                if !b4y! leq 9 if !b4y! geq 0 set /a "b4y=!b4y!-1"
                set "4,!b4y!=!b!"
                if !b5y! leq 9 if !b5y! geq 0 set /a "b5y=!b5y!-1"
                set "5,!b5y!=!b!"
                if !b6y! leq 9 if !b6y! geq 0 set /a "b6y=!b6y!-1"
                set "6,!b6y!=!b!"
                if !b7y! leq 9 if !b7y! geq 0 set /a "b7y=!b7y!-1"
                set "7,!b7y!=!b!"
                if !b8y! leq 9 if !b8y! geq 0 set /a "b8y=!b8y!-1"
                set "8,!b8y!=!b!"
                if !b9y! leq 9 if !b9y! geq 0 set /a "b9y=!b9y!-1"
                set "9,!b9y!=!b!"


            :: The board ::
            cls
            echo.
            echo   ############
            echo   #!0,9!!1,9!!2,9!!3,9!!4,9!!5,9!!6,9!!7,9!!8,9!!9,9!#
            echo   #!0,8!!1,8!!2,8!!3,8!!4,8!!5,8!!6,8!!7,8!!8,8!!9,8!#
            echo   #!0,7!!1,7!!2,7!!3,7!!4,7!!5,7!!6,7!!7,7!!8,7!!9,7!#
            echo   #!0,6!!1,6!!2,6!!3,6!!4,6!!5,6!!6,6!!7,6!!8,6!!9,6!#
            echo   #!0,5!!1,5!!2,5!!3,5!!4,5!!5,5!!6,5!!7,5!!8,5!!9,5!#
            echo   #!0,4!!1,4!!2,4!!3,4!!4,4!!5,4!!6,4!!7,4!!8,4!!9,4!#
            echo   #!0,3!!1,3!!2,3!!3,3!!4,3!!5,3!!6,3!!7,3!!8,3!!9,3!#
            echo   #!0,2!!1,2!!2,2!!3,2!!4,2!!5,2!!6,2!!7,2!!8,2!!9,2!#
            echo   #!0,1!!1,1!!2,1!!3,1!!4,1!!5,1!!6,1!!7,1!!8,1!!9,1!#
            echo   #!0,0!!1,0!!2,0!!3,0!!4,0!!5,0!!6,0!!7,0!!8,0!!9,0!#
            echo   ############


        ::Checking for player input ::
:getinput
        for /f "delims=" %%x in (control.txt) do set dir=%%x
:checkinput
        if %dir% equ left set "px=!px!-1"
        if %dir% equ right set "px=!px!+1"
        if %dir% equ pause goto pause
        if %dir% equ quit goto end

        echo stop>>control.txt


        :: Choosing Boulder placement 
:chooseboulder1
        set /a "num=%random%*10/32768"
        if !b0y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b1y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b2y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b3y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b4y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b5y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b6y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b7y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b8y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
        if !b9y! leq 9 goto chooseboulder2
:chooseboulder2
        if !num! equ 0 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 1 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 2 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 3 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 4 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 5 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 6 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 7 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 8 goto chooseboulder
        if !num! equ 9 goto chooseboulder
        set "b!num!y=9"

    :: Delaying the game 0.5 seconds to make it easier to play ::
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
    ping localhost -n 1 >nul
)
goto loop


:pause
for /f "delims=" %%x in (control.txt) do set pause=%%x
if %pause% equ left goto checkinput
if %pause% equ right goto checkinput
if %pause% equ pause goto checkinput
if %pause% equ quit goto end

:end
del control.txt
mode con cols=15 lines=4
cls
echo    GAME OVER
echo     1) Menu
echo     2) Exit
choice /c 12 /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto menu
if %errorlevel% equ 2 exit

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: The following line(s) are color settings. Do not delete them. ::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
0f
```

This problem is keeping me from releasing this code for everybody on the internet to enjoy. If I get a solution, the person who helped will get their name included in the list of developers, along with a link to their stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Choosing Boulder placement you have `:chooseboulder1` and `:chooseboulder2` labels, but after some lines you jump to a non-existent label

```
:chooseboulder2
        if !num! equ 0 goto chooseboulder
```

should be

```
:chooseboulder2
        if !num! equ 0 goto chooseboulder1
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe that I made such a dumb mistake :)